# How to make an html table background 50% transparent

Tags: html, css

I have to make an email template table background 50% transparent and white in color. I have used the following code

```
<table  role="presentation" border="0"  cellpadding="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width:200px; min-width:250px; margin: auto; border: 1px solid white;background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); ">
```

When it go through an email client the background is always 100% transparent. I even tried rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); but still 100% transparent. I can't use opacity as it doesn't work in some browsers.

Thanks

Comment: It depends if the client you are testing with supports RGBA. But, given the fact that RGBA values are a CSS3 feature, I do not think it will work with any client you test it on.

Comment: Both HSLA and RGBA color values are supported in: IE9+, Firefox 3+, Chrome, Safari, and Opera 10+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the best possible compatibility with all the email clients and browsers your best bet will be to create a semi transparent 1x1 pixel *.png* image and set it as a background to your table.

```css
table  {
    background: url(http://yourdomain.com/semi-transparent.png)
}
```

Comment: There are way more email clients blocking images (including background ones) than clients not supporting `rgba()` for `background-color`.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Fair point, but there is a good chance OP has quite a few images in the email already (emails with no images are virtually non-existent nowadays) and the users have to click *"download images"* anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Opacity for cross browser implementation

```
.table_class {
  /* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);

  /* Netscape */
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Safari 1.x */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Good browsers */
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: I believe you missed the point of the question. OP doesn't want to change the opacity of the contents, but only the transparency of the background color. However, they want to make it in a particular email client which they have forgot to mention or have purposefully avoided mentioning. It's probably a secret.

Comment: _However, they want to make it in a particular email client which they have forgot to mention or have purposefully avoided mentioning_ Is there such a technique?

Comment: `background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5)` will do in most browsers.

Comment: background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5) or background: rgba(255,255,255,.5) come as 100% transparent! I am using either Putsmail or Responsys to test my emails.

Comment: @Massey I happen to believe you've been wrongly informed. I have put together all the info I have on the subject in an answer. Take care.